# UIProgressView update itself in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiprogressview

I've a UITableView populated with several custom UITableViewCell. In one of them I have a UIProgressView that will represent a percentage of data.
However when I set a progress (let's say 50%), the progress bar appear at 50% and update itself until it reach 100%...

Here the code I use to update the data :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *CellIdentifier = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    if ([appliedTheme hasPrefix:@"DarkMode"]) {

        self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.20 green:0.20 blue:0.20 alpha:1.0];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.20 green:0.20 blue:0.20 alpha:1.0];
        cell.cardView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.30 green:0.30 blue:0.30 alpha:1.0];


        cell.storageIntroLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.storageInfoTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.deviceStorageTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    }else {

        self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.92 green:0.92 blue:0.92 alpha:1.0];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.92 green:0.92 blue:0.92 alpha:1.0];
        cell.cardView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


        cell.storageIntroLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.storageInfoTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.deviceStorageTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    }


    if ([CellIdentifier isEqualToString:@"storageIntro"]) {

        cell.storageIntroImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:storageIntroIconToShow];
        cell.storageIntroLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        cell.storageIntroLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        [cell.storageIntroLabel sizeToFit];
        cell.storageIntroLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Here you can find informations about your storage and how FileStore is using your memory by types of files", nil);

    }else if ([CellIdentifier isEqualToString:@"storageInfo"]){

        cell.storageInfoTitle.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Storage Informations", nil);
        cell.deviceStorageTitle.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        cell.deviceStorageTitle.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Device Storage", nil);
        cell.totalDeviceSpaceLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        cell.totalDeviceSpaceLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Total space :", nil);
        cell.finalTotalDeviceSpaceLabel.text = totalDeviceSpaceString;
        cell.freeDeviceSpaceLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        cell.freeDeviceSpaceLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Free space :", nil);
        cell.finalFreeDeviceSpaceLabel.text = totalDeviceFreeSpaceString;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [cell.deviceStorageProgressView setProgress:50 animated:YES];

        });

    }else {



    }


    return cell;

}
```

Even if I doesn't use the bool `animated:YES`,  the progress bar update itself over the time from the percentage I've set...
It doesn't mean anything to me ! Do I have to put the UIProgressView settings in another cell's delegate method ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to UIProgressView [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiprogressview/1619846-setprogress)

> The current progress is represented by a floating-point value between 0.0 and 1.0, inclusive, where 1.0 indicates the completion of the task. The default value is 0.0. Values less than 0.0 and greater than 1.0 are pinned to those limits.

You are setting it to **50** which will basically be converted to upper value 1. You need to give value as **0.5** if you want 50% progress.

Comment: Oh... Shame on me ! That's the kind of mistake you do when you're too much tired ^^' I'll test it tonight and validate your answer, thanks ;)